# VS2017 enterprise installer fails with "unable to download installation files"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am running the following VS2017 installation file:

mu_visual_studio_enterprise_2017_version_15.2_x86_x64_10436506

However, after a brief pause I get the following error:

[image]

- I have an internet connection
- I have tried running as Admin
- I have tried installing the certs (via the Digital Signatures tab) of the file properties

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, it's happens!

1. Run task manager and chek if any running instances of installation processes (end installation processes);
2. Run setup AGAIN!
3. If progress less than 10% for more than 2-3 minutes - goto step 1.

PS. on this stage downloader download approximately 70MB archive, not allow more than 20 minutes for this grand task.